# How to planning tasks with junior developers?

Tags: agile, scrum, team, junior-programmer, team-leader

As I am only senior developer in team, Others are juniors who not strong to write clean code and architect.

Problem is the during sprint planning, It took very hard time for me to lead technical decision during sprint planning because juniors doesn't have ideas to make any decision.

Most of decision come from me with my perspective. Certainly it will not come with best or even good enough decision.

1. Is it good to discuss every technical detail in sprint planning (Everyone know how to implement every tasks)?
2. If yes then how you handle if juniors has no decision mind?
3. If no then it means members take responsibility their own tasks? How quality and transparency can be control?

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Your team needs to learn how to program; then they can practice Scrum.

Comment: I don't think this is too broad at all. Dev methodology is Agiile/Scrum. Team is 1 senior developer and a bunch of juniors. Tech stack is irrelevant and this question really cuts to the heart of leading an Agile team. Having dealt with this exact scenario myself, I think we should reopen this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in a position that needs to be aware what's happening in every task and the junior team are not able to deliver a task without some help.

> Is it good to discuss every technical detail in sprint planning
>   (Everyone know how to implement every tasks)?

Yes, since your manager agree with this, because the plannings will be very long and, at least initially, the junior team will slow down a bit the deliver of the tasks.

If you are not able to discuss the details, you need another way to know **what** and **how** they are doing the tasks. You will need to do some **pair programming** and make every single task pass through a **code review** before being considered *DONE*.

> If yes then how you handle if juniors has no decision mind?

Discussing the technical details will turn the junior team more aware what is important and what is not. The objective here is make them gradually less dependent on you. Without explaining for them where they are wandering or being right, they will never let you.

You can also stay closer to the junior developer who realizes that he learns faster than the others and have more initiative among them. He will help you to check what the others developers are doing and reinforce some aspects already discussed without calling you every time.

Comment: Not to mention you should try to discuss with your juniors, you should really bring up the convincing arguments and receive common acceptance, if not listen thoroughly what they're arguing about and maybe refine your theories.